# How do I add a logout function?

Tags: java

I have included in a Login function for my eDepot system (using Eclipse) but I'm not sure how to do a logout function. I've tried several after researching it but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
package uk.ac.livjm.cms; //Name of package

import java.util.Scanner; //Imports scanner
import java.io.IOException; //Imports IOException

public class Depot { //Name of Program

  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String User = "SFoster"; //Username of Manager 1
    String Pass = "001"; //Password of Manager 1
    String Username = "BSamuel"; //Username of Manager 2
    String Password = "002"; //Password of Manager 2
    String User1 = "1"; //Username of Driver 1
    String Pass1 = "111"; //Password of Driver 1
    String Username1 = "2"; //Username of Driver 2
    String Password1 = "222"; //Password of Driver 2
    String User2 = "3"; //Username of Driver 3
    String Pass2 = "333"; //Password of Driver 3
    String inputuser; // Input when user is typing their username in
    String inputpass; // Input when user is typing their password in
    int menu = 0; //Displays menu
    int count = 0;
    int input;

    System.out.println(
        "Are you a Manager or a Driver or are you Creating a new account?"
            + "\n"
            + "1. Manager"
            + "\n"
            + "2. Driver"
            + "\n"
            + "3. Creating a new account"); //Displays message
    input = console.nextInt();

    if (input == 3) {
      DepotSystem.Account();
    }

    if (input == 1) { //Login for Manager

      System.out.println("Managers Login"); //Displays message
      System.out.println(
          "Please Note: You will only be allowed to re-enter your Username and Password three times."); //Displays message
      while (count < 3) // 3 menu options
      {
        System.out.println("Enter your Username:"); //Displays message
        inputuser = console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Password:"); //Displays message
        inputpass = console.next();

        if (inputuser.equals(User) && inputpass.equals(Pass)
            || (inputuser.equals(Username) && inputpass.equals(Password))) {
          System.out.println(
              "You have successfully logged in."
                  + "\n"
                  + "Welcome to the Managers Section!"
                  + "\n"
                  + "Enter the Number that corresponds to the option you wish to choose:");
          System.out.println(
              "1. Transfer available depot to another vehicle."
                  + "\n"
                  + "2. Set up new work schedule."
                  + "\n"
                  + "3. Search for available driver and vehicle."
                  + "\n"
                  + "4. Log out.");
          menu = console.nextInt();

          if (menu == 1) {
            System.out.println("Transfer available depot to another vehicle.");

            Transfer.transfer();

            count = 0;
            break;
          } else if (menu == 2) {
            System.out.println("Set up new work schedule.");

            WorkSchedule WorkSchedule = new WorkSchedule();
            uk.ac.livjm.cms.WorkSchedule.work();

            count = 0;
            break;
          } else if (menu == 3) {
            System.out.println("Search for available driver and vehicle.");

            Vehicle Vehicle = new Vehicle();
            uk.ac.livjm.cms.Vehicle.vehi();

            count = 0;
            break;
          }

          if (menu == 4) {
            System.out.println("Log out.");
            count = 0;
            break;
          } else {
            System.out.println(menu + ": Invalid option.");
            count++;
          }

        } else {
          System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (input == 2) {

      System.out.println("Drivers Login");
      System.out.println(
          "Please Note: You will only be allowed to re-enter your Username and Password three times.");
      while (count < 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter your Username: ");
        inputuser = console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Password: ");
        inputpass = console.next();

        if (inputuser.equals(User1) && inputpass.equals(Pass1)
            || (inputuser.equals(Username1) && inputpass.equals(Password1))
            || (inputuser.equals(User2) && inputpass.equals(Pass2))) {
          System.out.println(
              "You have successfully logged in."
                  + "\n"
                  + "Welcome to the Drivers Section!"
                  + "\n"
                  + "Enter the Number that corresponds to the option you wish to choose: ");
          System.out.println("1. View Work Schedule." + "\n" + "2. Log Out.");
          menu = console.nextInt();

          if (menu == 1) {
            System.out.println("View Work Schedule.");

            WorkScheduleDriver.workdriver();

            count = 0;
            break;
          } else if (menu == 2) {
            System.out.println("Log out.");
            count = 0;
            break;
          } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in a mess, this is not the right way to do this, but as per your code you have a while loop that runs while count is < 3 and in the logout section rather than setting count to zero , set it to 3 or any other number so that it breaks from the while loop, that would simulate logout. that is :-

```
else if (menu == 2)
{
    System.out.println("Log out.");
    count = 3;  // set to 3
}
```

more over you have a lot of unneccessary break statements in your code such as `count = 0; break;`, you can either set again count to 3 or use break alone instead of `count = 0` which is unnecessary there, and also you could create a seperate login method and compare with usrename and password there there by reducing a few lines of code.